# Xcode 4.2: Compile error (Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255 )

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xib

Installed Xcode 4.2 on fresh OS X Lion on my MacBook Air, and can't compile my old projects. Create new single-window project (View-based app) - do not make any changes, just try to compile it and got error:

```
CompileXIB Test3/en.lproj/ViewController.xib
    cd /Volumes/MacExt/Projects/iOS/Test3
    setenv IBC_MINIMUM_COMPATIBILITY_VERSION 5.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    setenv XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH /Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/lial/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test3-fvcbdbtitujnwabzsgjgcbugfmoy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Test3.app/en.lproj/ViewController.nib /Volumes/MacExt/Projects/iOS/Test3/Test3/en.lproj/ViewController.xib
--sdk /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk

Command /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool failed with exit code 255
```

Trying to open xib got Internal error with choice: Crash and Continue

```
Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose "Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent state.  Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of all unsaved data.
```

Please help me, how can I fix this problem? Is Xcode not stable? Or do some of my projects have incorrect settings?

Comment: Forget to tell: I run on iPhone 5.0 Simulator with the same Deployment target

Comment: Make sure that the SourceCode for the xib has all necessary files listed in the <Resources> section.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same thing. It turned out to be a duplicate UILabel in the storyboard due to a git merge. Apparently Xcode will crash if two UI elements have the same internal ID.

My method for finding the responsible issue was:

- Iteratively step backward through the git history, checking out each commit until you find the first storyboard that doesn't crash Xcode.
- Once you have the commit that started crashing, check out HEAD and iteratively revert the storyboard changes in the problem commit. Continue to narrow it down until you have the one UI element or one line that will cause a crash.
- Revert the responsible change permanently and restart Xcode. Open the storyboard again and you may be warned about an internal inconsistency. Agree to the proposed changes Xcode makes, but review them.
- If necessary, you may now attempt to re-create the UI element or changes from scratch that were causing the problem before.